# How can I bind 8 checkboxes in MainWindow.xaml to each bit of a byte property of ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am fairly new to WPF and MVVM. What I'm trying to achieve is that I have eight checkboxes in my GUI which I need to convert to a single byte value so that I can serially transmit it at any given time. Will I have to create 8 bool properties and then convert them to a byte property?

This is my XAML currently. I have binded each checkbox individually to a byte property. Can I bind them all to one property somehow to make a byte where each checkbox represents a bit.

```
<Window x:Class="ModelClassTest.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
        <CheckBox Margin="10,10,0,0"  Content="Bit 0" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit0}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,30,0,0" Content="Bit 1" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit1}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,50,0,0" Content="Bit 2" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit2}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,70,0,0" Content="Bit 3" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit3}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,90,0,0" Content="Bit 4" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit4}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,110,0,0" Content="Bit 5" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit5}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,130,0,0" Content="Bit 6" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit6}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,150,0,0" Content="Bit 7" IsChecked="{Binding Path Bit7}"/>
        <Button Width="100" Height="20" Margin="10,173,408.723,128.076" Content="Transmit" Command="{Binding ClickMe}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes you can bind them to one property but you will have to use a Converter with your Binding. If you are new with WPF I would recommend you don't use Margins, it will make ui like it's winforms. Look into how to use different containers, ListView would fit nicely here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the checkboxes manually, you could create an `ItemsControl` for all the bits of your byte. Represent the byte with a list of single bits.

Create a viewmodel class for the sigle bit:

```
// The ViewModelBase base class implements INotifyPropertyChanged
// and provides the SetProperty method
class Bit : ViewModelBase 
{
    private bool _isSet;

    public Bit(int bitNumber)
    {
        BitNumber = bitNumber;
    }

    public int BitNumber { get; }

    public bool IsSet
    {
        get => _isSet;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isSet, value);
    }
}
```

Here is your byte in the main viewmodel:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Bit> Byte { get; }
    = new List<Bit>(Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(v => new Bit(v)));
```

In the main viewmodel, create an `ICommand` that will convert your list of bits to a byte and use this value. Alternatively, create a property of type `byte` that will calculate the value on-the-fly based on the single bits. Here is how the implementation could look like:

```
void UseByte()
{
    var byteValue = Byte.Select((v, i) => (1 << i) * (v.IsSet ? 1 : 0)).Sum();

    // use the value as needed
}
```

And this is how your view could look like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Byte}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSet}">
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="Bit "/><Run Text="{Binding BitNumber, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </CheckBox>        
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be trying both your method as well as BionicCode's method :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the binding with a converter attached in order to read the byte value from the view model and a `ICommand` to toggle a specific bit in the byte:

**ByteToBitConverter.cs**

```
class ByteToBiteConverter : IValueConverter
{    
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => 
    value is byte byteValue 
      && int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out int bitPosition)
        ? new BitArray(new Byte[] {byteValue}).Get(bitPosition - 1)
        : Binding.DoNothing;

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();  
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
  private byte byteValue;
  public byte ByteValue 
  {
    get => this.byteValue;
    set
    {
      this.byteValue = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ICommand ToggleBitCommand => new RelayCommand(ToggleBit);
  public int BitCount { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.ByteValue = 128;
  }

  private void ToggleBit(object commandParameter)
  {
    if (!int.TryParse(commandParameter.ToString(), out int bitPosition))
    {
      return;
    }

    var bytes = new Byte[] { this.ByteValue };
    var boolArray = new bool[this.BitCount];
    var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
    int toggleBitIndex = bitPosition - 1;

    bits.Set(toggleBitIndex, !bits.Get(toggleBitIndex));

    bytes = new Byte[1];
    bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    this.ByteValue = bytes.FirstOrDefault();
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }  

  #endregion
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**
(Implementation taken from [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic))

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields 
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    #endregion // Fields 
    #region Constructors 
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute; _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors 
    #region ICommand Members 
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _execute(parameter); }
    #endregion // ICommand Members 
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ByteToBitByteConverter />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>

    <!-- 
      CommandParameter is the bit position. 
      Binding.Mode of IsChecked has to be explicitely set to BindingMode.OneWay
    -->
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit0" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="1" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit1" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="2" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit2" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="3" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit3" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="4" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=4}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit4" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="5" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit5" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="6" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=6}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit6" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="7" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=7}" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Bit7" 
              Command="{Binding ToggleBitCommand}"
              CommandParameter="8" 
              IsChecked="{Biding ByteValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitConverter}, ConverterParameter=8}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be trying both your method as well as dymanoid's method :)